# iPhone - is CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor not creating wanted color?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cgcontext, uicolor

I am having some weird troubles with drawing some lines in an application.
My drawRect is using

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:57 green:172 blue:255 alpha:1].CGColor]);
CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.8);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, POLYLINE_WIDTH);
```

The color that is supposed to be shown is something like [this.](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=CALC&E1=57.07&E2=172.05&E3=255.00) However I am getting a dark grey color, does anyone know why this color could be getting skewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:57 / 255 green:172 / 255 blue:255 / 255 alpha:1].CGColor]);`

These functions are expecting a number from 0-1.

Comment: I tried just doing the division myself and putting it in but that wouldn't even work:

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.223529412 green:0.674509804 blue:1 alpha:1]);

Comment: Don't forget the `.CGColor]` part, that function is expecting it, not a UIColor.

Comment: This was all user error on my part, but I appreciate reminding me that each value must be less than 1!